# Scroll the UICollectionView Background With The UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am building an app that is presenting articles from a blog.  I am using UICollectionView to present images that are parsed from the blog for each of the cells.  This is my first go-round with a UICollectionView so I am wondering how you set up a background image of something like shelves that will scroll with the UICollectionView?

I have tried using:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelves.jpg"]];
```

But this doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying:

```
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelves.jpg"]];
```

should work. I do exactly this in `viewDidLoad` and it works for me. I would check that you're getting a valid image. Perhaps "shelves.jpg" needs to be added to the project?

Comment: shelves was there, just was such a large file that only the edges (which were white) were visible, making it look like nothing loaded.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the size of a `UIImageView` for your background to a size that is larger than the current `UIView` size then change the origin (increment) of that `UIImageView` based on your current visible cells for your `UICollectionView`. This would give you a side scrolling (parallax) effect based on which cells are currently being viewed.

There are other [parallax effects](https://github.com/modocache/MDCParallaxView) people have created that you can get creative with to apply to your scenario. The idea is pretty simple.